# Radio type stream catching in mvc .net

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a function of playing audio which I am passing through a streaming server. Whenever I logged in to the website and hit the radio button it begins to stream the audio I've been streaming from my vlc or other streaming software.

```
 <td id="songPlayer" data-audio="@item.SongPath">
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    <button id="playButton" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning-custom"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></i></button>
                                    <button id="addSongToList" name="@item.Id" class="btn btn-sm btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </td>
```

This is where it's getting the source:

```
 $("#songPlayer #playButton").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#songName").html($(this).parent().parent().parent().children(':nth-child(2)').html());




        var dataAudio = $(this).parent().parent().attr("data-audio");
        player.pause();
        player.load();
        player.setSrc(dataAudio);
        player.play();
    });
```

My query is to play the audio file but I want it to play the file I've been streaming from the broadcaster or streamer program. I can play the audio of the stored file but cannot play the live streaming.

Comment: Can you show the html for the parent() transversal madness you got going on there